# VBA Macro Pivot Table Filter Error

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

In my spreadsheet, I have variable data; however, I have a specific set of attributes that I'd want to be filtered upon if/when they do appear in the data run for that week. If they do not appear, I'd like the Pivot Table filter to skip over it and continue to the next.
Unfortunately, I keep getting debugging errors when I try to run my macro. Can anyone help?

I.E.
If "1G1N13S2" isn't in the variable [raw] data, it'd carry me straight to the VBA to debug instead of skipping over it (whether false or true) to continue on to the subsequent ID#.

```
'PivotTable
FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=ActiveSheet.UsedRange). _
    CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion10
    ActiveSheet.PivotTableWizard TableDestination:=ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 1)
    ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 1).Select

' BCA_Other Macro
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("ACTIVITY_ID")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable1").PivotFields("SUM_$"), "Count of SUM_$", xlCount
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Count of SUM_$")
    .Caption = "Sum of SUM_$"
    .Function = xlSum
    .NumberFormat = "#,##0.00_);[Red](#,##0.00)"
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("WK_END_DATE")
    .Orientation = xlColumnField
    .Position = 1
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("WK_END_DATE")
    .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("ANALYSIS_TYPE")
    .Orientation = xlPageField
    .Position = 1
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("ANALYSIS_TYPE"). _
    CurrentPage = "ACT"
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("BUS_UNIT_GL_FROM")
    .Orientation = xlPageField
    .Position = 1
End With
  ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("BUS_UNIT_GL_FROM"). _
    CurrentPage = "AV"

  'Activity ID Filter
  With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("ACTIVITY_ID")
    .PivotItems("1G1N13S2").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("1G1N2SAN").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("1G1N5ACC").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("1G1N5SCI").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("1G1N5SDV").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("1G1N5SMS").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("1G1N5SST").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("1G1N9BAT").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("1G1N9EBT").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("1G1N9EPL").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("E6T66ZAV").Visible = True
    .PivotItems("E6T66ZB3").Visible = True
    .PivotItems("E6T66ZB4").Visible = True
    .PivotItems("E6T66ZB5").Visible = True
    .PivotItems("E6T66ZCU").Visible = True
    .PivotItems("E6T66ZDX").Visible = True
    .PivotItems("E6T66ZE9").Visible = True
    .PivotItems("E6T66ZIL").Visible = True
    .PivotItems("E6T66ZIS").Visible = True
    .PivotItems("E6T66ZIV").Visible = True
    .PivotItems("E6T66ZIZ").Visible = True
    .PivotItems("E6T66ZJ6").Visible = True
    .PivotItems("E6T66ZJ8").Visible = True
    .PivotItems("E6T66ZJA").Visible = True
    .PivotItems("EMAD0005").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("EMADF006").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("F8800YN5").Visible = True
    .PivotItems("F8800YNU").Visible = True
    .PivotItems("F8800YNW").Visible = True
    .PivotItems("F8800YPM").Visible = True

End With

'Add new tabs for Hours and rename tabs to Dollars and Hours
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "BCA_Other_Dlrs"
Sheets("BCA_Other_Dlrs").Select
Sheets("BCA_Other_Dlrs").Copy Before:=Sheets(1)
Range("B18").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Sum of SUM_$").Orientation _
    = xlHidden
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("SUM_HOURS")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 2
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("SUM_HOURS").Orientation = _
    xlHidden
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable1").PivotFields("SUM_HOURS"), "Count of SUM_HOURS", xlCount
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Count of SUM_HOURS")
    .Caption = "Sum of SUM_HOURS"
    .Function = xlSum
    .NumberFormat = "#,##0.0_);[Red](#,##0.0)"
```

Comment: What are the "debugging errors" and where do they occur?

Answer (score 1):

So, I've gotten an answer as to how to fix this.

```
On Error Resume Next
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("ACTIVITY_ID")
.PivotItems("1G1N13S2").Visible = False
.PivotItems("1G1N2SAN").Visible = False
.PivotItems("1G1N5ACC").Visible = False
.PivotItems("1G1N5SCI").Visible = False
.PivotItems("1G1N5SDV").Visible = False
.PivotItems("E6T66ZJA").Visible = True
End With
On Error Goto 0
```